# Community Forgot Password Email Template picking up incorrect merge fields values - Spring 22 Preview Effect

Tags: email-template, digital-experience, vf-email-template, release-update

## Background

We've been using Visualforce Email Template for a Community forgot password emails that used to work fine until a few days ago. The emails are triggered using `Site.forgotPassword(username, emailTemplateName)`& are sent in guest user context from a Without sharing class.

### Email Template

The email template uses a few merge field from User object.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="{!$Label.EmailSubject}" language="{!Recipient.LanguageLocaleKey}" recipientType="User" >
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <html>
            <div>
                Dear {!$User.FirstName},
                <br/>
                Please use this link to reset your password.....
            </div>
        </html>
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

## Problem

Since Spring 22 sandbox preview started. The emails are sent with incorrect merge field values. Some of them are sent with `Site Guest User` details. In fact, the email is sent to the correct user email. However, the email body that is generated has incorrect merge field values for the User object.

The email user receives,

```
Dear <Site Guest User>,
Please use this link to reset your password......
```

A few time it is sent from scratch org admin,

```
Dear User User,
.......
```

---

## When

After Spring 22 preview started we've been seeing some issues with Emails that use Visualforce based Email Templates. The emails are triggered from Community `Site.forgotPassword(username, emailTemplateName)`.
This issue is replicable with spring 22 preview scratch orgs & works fine if they're on Winter 22.

## Question

I could not find anything in the release notes, neither a known issue nor any supporting doc that confirms this is caused by Spring 22 preview.

1. Have you seen something similar, any supporting doc what likely have caused it?
2. Are there any recent changes related to guest user?

To me, this looks like a bug with the email template.

Comment: Possibly related to the ongoing [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000xb5TQAQ) ?

Comment: Possibly not! users are receiving emails in this case.

Comment: I have seen a customer's case who reported this same behavior and the issue got fixed after a fix has been rolled out for [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000xb5T) . Can you please check for your instance and confirm ?

Comment: The patch released fixed this issue but broke something else now we're getting internal server error when we call `Site.forgotPassword`. I'll update the question with other details & case with SF.

Comment: Thanks,Sachin. A bug has been tagged to the ISE  https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002CKzgQAG and the product team are working on fixing it

Comment: Thank you @Swetha, support also mentioned that they're working on the fix under the same KI you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

### 26th JAN 2022

Based on Case with Salesforce Support. It has been confirmed as a bug. They mentioned the Product team is working on a similar [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000000xb5TQAQ), and if the issue still doesn't resolve they will rollout another patch for this specific issue.

### 27th JAN 2022

SF rolled out the patch to impacted orgs. The issue mentioned here has been fixed. But it started to break & errors with `internal server error` once call to `Site.forgotPassword() hits.` Don't know how the email works.

### 29th JAN 2022

We're still waiting for another patch release to fix the internal server error. Salesforce support mentioned that the Product team is working on the fix under another KI [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002CKzgQAG).

### 2nd FEB 2022

Salesforce rolled out another patch & every works fine now.